# Can you change text-color if a certain word is used in the text?

Tags: php, xml

This code:

```
$url = ('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=604');

  function Feed($url) {
    $feed = simplexml_load_file($url) or die('Can not connect to server');
    $result = array();
    foreach ($feed->channel->item as $content) {
        array_push($result, $content);
    }
    return $result;
}

$title = 'Ev 134 Haukelifjell'; // Tittel som søkes for

foreach(Feed('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=604') as $f ) {
    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false)
        echo $f->description;
}
```

Could output something like this:

```
Vær- og føreforhold: Stort sett snø- og isdekke, fare for glatte partier og redusert sikt. Klokken 06:15 var det -2 grader, liten kuling og middels snøbyger. Gjelder fra: 12.01.2020 06:21
```

the output is probably in an unknown language for you, but its a weather report. if the weather is so bad that the road gets closed (yes this happens in Norway) it would say it here.

What I want:
if the word "closed" is in this text I want to echo "closed" in red. If not just "open" and green. But if it echo "could be closed" I would still have the green "open". Write search terms in English, I will translate my self.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your language so I'll type the search terms in englisch. You have to translate it yourself.

```
$green_color    = 'green';
$red_color      = 'red';
$closed_text    = 'closed';               // here your closed text
$exception_text = 'could be closed';     // here your open exception text

    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){

        // if the word closed is found
        if(strpos($f->description, $closed_text) !== false){

            // if the word closed is found,check if it's not part of the exception
            // class. if not, show red closed else show open in green.
            // 
            // - info: this is ternary operator. Different way of writing if/else
            echo strpos($f->description, $exception_text) === false) ? 
                 '<span style="color:'.$red_color.'">closed</span>' : 
                 '<span style="color:'.$green_color.'">open</span>'

        }else{
            // if no closed word is found. show open in green. 
            echo '<span style="color:'.$green_color.'">open</span>'
        }
      }
```

I've used the ternary operator in this example. Could be interesting to learn about: 
https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators